# TortoiseGit icons overlays icons on desktop

Tags: git, windows-10, tortoisegit

TortoisGit always overlays my **desktop**-icons (after a variable time of working) with icon-overlays from TortoiseGit wrongly, although the desktop-folder isn't a git-project folder.

The problem occurs on Windows 10 (same on Windows 7 before), with latest versions of git 2.10.0 and TortoiseGit 2.3.0.0.

The TortoiseGit settings for icon-overlay are:

- Status cache: Default
- Drive Types: Only "Fixed drives" activated
- Excluded paths: "C:\*" (Where the Desktop-Folder is in)
- Included paths: "G:\*" (Where my git-projekts are in)
- Show excluded folders as normal: Checked

Any ideas who to solve the problem, that desktop-icons never will be overlayed by TortoiseGit-Icon-Overlay?

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be fixed with the release of 2.5.0.0 (released on 2017-07-23).